# I am trying to begin learning react, and i am trying to use vite but npm keeps giving me an error every time I run the command

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, vite, git-bash

I am a junior dev, and I am trying to learn react. I'm starting with vite and when running the command 'npm create vite@latest' I am getting the following:

[git bash error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7reu.png)

Following the path to the log of this run, this is the log:
[verbose error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJcM3.png)

I have tried the following:

- Uninstalling and reinstalling nodejs
- Checked Environment Variables
- Confirmed Node.js and npm Executables
- Restarted Command Prompt and my
  computer
- Verified Node.js and npm Versions, both are up to date

I am lost on where to go next. I've spent hours trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to create a new project? When creating a new project with Vite, the command should be npm init vite@latest, not npm create vite@latest.

Comment: I am still getting the same error, yes it is a new project.